# why is my my ram 99% used when i open visual studio code and android emulator only

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-emulator, ram

when I open android emulator and android studio 98-99% of my ram is used I have an 8gb ram device
what should I do I tried installing a lower version of the api I used but still I have that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it by decreasing the ram I gave it to the emulator I used to give it 2gb ram now I figured out 512mb is enough.